# How to get max and min value with other column's values in excel?

Tags: excel

I want to get max and min values with other column's values in ms excel 2007. I have two columns

```
| Column A | Column B |
-----------------------
|A         |   18     |
-----------------------
|B         |   78     |
-----------------------
|c         |   9      |
```

I want to  print out max values and min values of "Column B" with "Column A" values. Please suggest me some formula.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.What result do you expect in your example? What do you mean by "with column A values"?

Comment: @assylias Yes i need with column A values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following formula will find the max value in column B, and return the value from column A that is in the same row:

```
=INDEX(A:A,(MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0)))
```

In your example, the result would be "B".

Note that if the max value occurs in column B more than once, only the first one will be processed with this formula.

For minimum, just substitute MIN in place of MAX.

Answer (score 0):

One way: select a cell to output the data to e.g. D2. Then choose

Data > Consolidate...Function:Min,  Reference:$A:$B,  Use labels in: Left Column

and repeat with Function: Max.

Another way: use a pivot table.